# Share Common variable in Multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have code which convert one custom file format to other custom file format.

Used **multiprocessing** to divide work into parallel work. Some divide by process count logic to pass files list as a input argument.

**code:**

```
def CustomFun1(self, ):
    start_time = time.time()
    custom1_files = os.listdir("/Some/location")
    self.total_custom1_count = custom1_files.__len__()
    self.custom2_ctr = 0
    self.updateReport(2, 1, self.total_custom_count, -1, "")
    self.custom1_2_custom2_cmd = "command to convert custom1 to custom2"

    process_count = 4
    if process_count>1 and self.total_custom1_count>process_count:
        import multiprocessing
        mid = self.total_custom1_count/process_count
        processes = []
        start_index = 0
        end_index = 0 
        for ii in range(1, process_count):
            end_index += mid
            pp = multiprocessing.Process(name='custom12custom2_%s_%s'%(ii, time.time()),\
                                       target=self.createCustom1ToCustom2,\
                                       args=(custom1_files[start_index:end_index], ))
            pp.daemon = False
            processes.append(pp)
            start_index = end_index

        pp = multiprocessing.Process(name='custom12custom2_%s_%s'%(ii, time.time()),\
                                     target=self.createCustom1ToCustom2,\
                                     args=(custom1_files[start_index:], ))
        pp.daemon = False
        processes.append(pp)
        for pp in processes:
            pp.start()
        for pp in processes:
            pp.join()
    else:
        self.createCustom1ToCustom2(custom1_files)
    t2 = time.time() - start_time
    self.updateReport(2, 2, self.total_custom1_count, self.custom2_ctr, t2)

def createCustom1ToCustom2(self, custom1_files):
    """ Create Custom2 from the Custom1. """
    try:
        for cnt, custom1_file in enumerate(custom1_files, 1):
            ret = os.system(self.custom1_2_custom2_cmd%(custom1_file, custom1_file.split('.')[0]))
            self.custom2_ctr += 1 
            if self.custom2_ctr%5==0:
                self.updateReport(2, 1, self.total_custom1_count, self.custom2_ctr, "")
    except:
        e = traceback.format_exc()
```

Following is function in which I write how many Custom1 type files are converted to Custom2 type file.

**Report Variable:**

```
self.report = [{"pn": "Extraction", "status": 0, "cnt": 0, "tt": 0},
               {"pn": "Basic conversion Generation", "status": 0, "cnt": 0, "cur_i": 0, "tt": 0},
               {"pn": "Cutom1 to custom2", "status": 0, "cnt": 0, "cur_i": 0, "tt": 0}
               ]
def updateReport(self, pos, status, cnt, cur_i, tt):
    if not self.reportLoc:
        return

    try:
        self.report[pos]["status"] = status
        self.report[pos]["cnt"] = cnt
        if tt:
            self.report[pos]["tt"] = datetime.fromtimestamp(tt).strftime('%H:%M:%S')

        self.report[pos]["cur_i"] = cur_i
        with open(self.reportLoc, "w") as fp:
            fp.write(simplejson.dumps(self.report))
    except Exception, e:
        e = traceback.format_exc()
```

**Multiprocessing is working and also get expected output**, This process takes 30 to 40 mints for 2000 files conversion and I need to show how many files are converted after 30 seconds or 1 mints. For-that I need the report file which written in the function `updateReport`.

1. `self.custom2_ctr` is not updated in code run by multiprocessing means value of  `self.custom2_ctr` is `0` at the end of function `CustomFun1`.
2. In function `updateReport`, code shear common `self.report`
   variable. How to set lock on function `updateReport` means **Only
   one process can shear this function at one time**?

Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Instead of checking in with the updateReport, why not have a global counter instead, incrementing each time you close a file in CustomFun1?

Comment: Global variable will be common for this py file, If at one time two or more users are using this feature then global variable while common for both. I face this problem in past.

Comment: If you really want to use updateReport, have a look at Synchroinzation and locking https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: Did you look at the documentation for the multiprocessing module? It defines lock and queue classes which seem to be exactly what you want.

Comment: Do take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16000687/6610.  Progress reporting is a solved problem :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use lock to synchronise updateReport.

Check here: [Synchronization between processes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html)